# Invoke-command through Jenkins pipeline always failed

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, hyper-v, invoke-command

I am triggering a powershell script via jenkins pipeline .
The script contains invoke-command code that I use to set up Hyper v and run commands on it .
The script works as expected on ISE, but not throgh Jenkins.
As it keeps failed with:

An error has occurred which Windows PowerShell cannot handle. A remote session might have ended.

> CategoryInfo : OpenError: (:String) , PSRemotingDataStructureException
> FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSSessionStateBroken

Comment: which line does the error come from? what is the code in this line?

Comment: Invoke-Command -VMName KKK-NYC-kWK -Credential $global:credential -ScriptBlock { (Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPV4 -InterfaceAlias Ethernet).IPAddress }